# Comparing two graphs, finding vertices that changed their positions

Tags: graphs

I have a task of comparing two organisation charts. These chart objects are described as a set of nodes (people) where each has a unique ID field and a parent ID field (pointing to another node's unique ID). For simplicity we can assume that there's only one node without a parent ID (head of the organisation) and that no node can reference itself. So it's essentially a tree of all the people in the organisation. Comparison should produce two lists - people who left the organisation, people who joined, and people who have changed their position in the organisation. Leavers and joiners are trivial, but I don't know how to proceed with people who changed their position. I need some ideas on how to proceed with identifying people who really moved within the chart from those who only have new parent IDs.

Comment: So directed graphs with out-degree at most one?  What is the running time you want for this?  Is this homework?

Comment: Not homework, running time doesn't matter. I'm trying to compare two organisation charts and find out which people changed their positions.

Comment: But you can simply check if all the vertices are present in the second graph?  Check if there are any new IDs in the new graph?  And check that the parent of a vertex in the new graph is the same as in the old one.  If this is about actually programming it, it's probably not computer science and more suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: it's not about programming or trivial parent id comparisons. the issue is that when a vertex is moved to another position (and another one takes its place) not only its own parent id is changing but also parent ids of its former (and new) children - for example when my manager is promoted and another person takes his place, my own parent id has changed, but my actual position didn't. I'm looking for some guidance on how to look into this problem, how do I find out which ones were actually moved and which ones stayed in their old "place in the graph". I'm very rusty in terminology :(

Comment: So you have trees? What exactly specifies the "position"? You are looking for an algorithm; with which restrictions? Do you have access to the individual updates?

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking.  What is the class of graphs?  Are they trees?  Where's the parent relation come from?  Is each node labelled with a unique identifier that doesn't change when it is "moved"?  If yes, why isn't this a trivial programming question?  (If not, this is some kind of graph isomorphism question?)  Why do I care about parent IDs?  Can't I just ignore them and look at the IDs of each node to match up where it was before and where it is now?  Please edit the question to be a lot clearer, and to tell us what you've tried.

Comment: @devmiles.com When you say, "...my own parent id has changed, but my actual position didn't", it sounds like you are implying there is more to your graph than vertices with a unique id and parent id?  That is, if a boss moves but none of the subordinates do, what makes that different than saying all the subordinates moved to be under their new boss?  I think your vertices need a unique id and a "job title".  Or no?

Comment: Another example, what if two leaf subordinates of a boss swap jobs?  Does that count as a move?  By your example of "actual position", it would.  But that would not change the graph if defined only by id and parent.

Comment: If a boss A gets a new boss B, but A takes his/her whole team with them, is that one move just for the boss, or a move for everyone in the team?

Comment: **Your current editing is not enough.**  You still do not describe
sufficiently the structure of your graph. Give a more formal
description, if you want your question to be taken seriously. As it s
described, there is simply not enough information in the grph to
determine the structure of the organization, or the position of people
in the organization. You can say who is the boss of who, but not who
is in dept A or in dept B, which obviously matter if you want to
determine who changed position.

Comment: @cape1232 I thought about someone taking his team with them too, let's consider them all to be movers.
Also, there's no concept of the job in the chart. I'm looking for a formal way to distinguish movers from people who simply got a new manager.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, I think this is a minimum edit distance problem.  Encode your graph in some canonical order (e.g. breadth-first, with tokens at each level sorted by id) with a token for each node and a token for each parent.  You want the [minimum edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between that encoding and the encoding of the new tree.

Minimum edit distance counts insertion, deletion, and substitution.  Seems to map naturally to your problem.

If what you really have is an org. chart where there are various jobs that define the org chart with people who fill the jobs, then you have two different problems.  You need to define your graph in terms of the jobs, and the min. edit distance algorithm is applicable to that.  You then need to encode who has which job, and the encoding will make finding people who changed jobs trivial.